# Images Not Appearing Asp.Net Core

Tags: css, asp.net, image, asp.net-core

I am attempting to use imported images in my .Net Project. I have placed the images in the images folder and they all have a plus sign and say "Pending add" next to them.

I'm not sure if this is the error or how I am referencing the images. I reference the image using the following code.

```
<img class="block" id="u730_img" src="Images/green9-crop-u730.jpg?crc=200722682" alt="" width="1529" height="659"/>
```

The image name is correct, but I'm not sure if that is the appropriate path. My folder structure is below. The file being used is LoginBody.cshtml and the image is in the images folder.

[image]

Comment: You need to add path like `"~/Images/green9-crop-u730.jpg"`

Comment: @Div when I add that, there's no change. Then when I debug and run inspect element it doesn't seem to have registered the "~" because it shows the path as /Images/...

Comment: @Div there's a 404 not found for the image as well as another image

Comment: @Div it doesn't look like anything is wrong. I copied the path from the properties menu itself

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect that you're using ASP.NET Core, and in newer version static files under `wwwroot` folder are served.

Move your images to `wwwroot` > `images` 
and change your path:

```
<img class="block" id="u730_img" src="~/Images/green9-crop-u730.jpg?crc=200722682" alt="" width="1529" height="659"/>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you!  You are the only person who fixed my problem.  I am using ASP.NET Core with MVC and I tried 20 different things.  Your answer was straight to the point and it worked.